# N::meprec Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics, evaluation

I get an N::meprec error message when testing a fairly simple expression involving square roots

```
N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating (-Sqrt[(3/10)]+Sqrt[5/6])/Sqrt[2]+(-Sqrt[(3/10)]+1/Sqrt[30])/Sqrt[2].
```

I want to make sure the result is <=10^-12 (which it should be).
Well,

```
(-Sqrt[3/10] + Sqrt[5/6])/Sqrt[2] + (-Sqrt[3/10] + Sqrt[1/30])/
   Sqrt[2] // Together
```

yields 0!

**Why this?** Is it an error not trying Together or other simplifications before going into  numerical computations?

Comment: The standard thing to try is something like `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, code]`. -- Of course, no one can reproduce your result with the `code`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The expression you show simplifies to zero exactly (e.g. try `Simplify` with it). Why shouldn't its numerical value be zero? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I had programmed a function which required that parameters are orthogonal vectors v1 and v3. To safeguard myself against calling my functions with non orthogonal arguments, I added `Assert[Abs[v1.v3] <= 10^-12];` The error first happend in this assert statement.